# Auto Close modal popup after form submit action

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

i tried a lot of solutions to make sure if i can find solution without posting this but all are too old and didn't helped.

Well i have a landing page popup for enquiry form on my website where modal popup opens and user fill up form. The only thing now i want is to auto close popup after the user submit form.

i tried this:

```
 <?php 
$your_email ='user@gmail.com';

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    //$user_message = $_POST['message'];
    ///------------Do Validations-------------

    if(empty($errors))
    {
        //send the email
        $to = $your_email;
        $subject="Enquiry from website";
        $from = $your_email;

        $body = "A user  $name submitted the contact form For your website:\n".
        "Name: $name\n".
        "Email: $visitor_email \n".
        "Contact No: $mobile \n";
        //"Message: $user_message\n\n"; 

        $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);
        echo "<script>alert('Thanks! for contacting us. We will get back to you within 24 hours.');</script>";
        //header('Location: contact');
        }
        }
?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function CloseAndRefresh() 
  {
     opener.location.reload(true);
     self.close();
  }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form class="contactForm" method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email ID">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Mobile</td>
            <td>
                <input name="mobile" type="text" maxlength="10" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile No">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit" onClick="CloseAndRefresh(); return:true;" id="btnsubmit" class="agree button">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: Try `window.close()` instead of `self.close()`

Comment: Tried but still same. As the modal popup opens at page load it just does same it refresh and open up again..

Comment: Did you check your developer console for errors?

Comment: what about `this.close()` ?

Comment: still not working..

Comment: any solution for this problem?